# Automate data transfer between workbooks in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I admit to not being very technical and my limit up to now has been using paste links to connect data between sheets. I now have a requirement I cannot figure out.

I have 2 workbooks I wish to automate sharing data between.

Workbook 1 contains multiple rows of data manually entered.

I need a button against each row so when it is pressed data from certain cells on that row in Workbook 1 are transferred to cells within a worksheet in workbook 2

I would be very grateful for any guidance on how to achieve this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though you can deploy VBA to achieve this, but the same is also possible with simple formula like.

```
   =[1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1
```

Lets say you have two workbooks `1.xlsx and 2.xlsx` and you want `sheet1/column A1` value from `1.xlsx` to be auto populated in `sheet1/column A1` in `2.xlsx`, you can simply link it with a formula like `=[1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1` in second workbook `2.xlsx`.

So as soon as some entry is done in first cell, second cell is auto populated

However if you are looking only for vba solution do write back

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, that is useful for some other scenarios on the sheets I am using.

Comment: The scenario is that I have a list of customer details -each new customer with address details etc. is added at the end of this list in book 1. I then at the moment have to cut and paste name, address, reference etc. into a separate book 2 which contains a template for a job record to be printed out. The details on that sheet then are linked(through normal paste link) to other sheets within workbook 2.  I had envisaged having a submit button against each row ready so when details are entered certain cells which then automatically fill in the template in Book 2

Comment: It is very much possible, but without looking at the file its quite difficult to guide you. Furthermore at the very outset you have mentioned about being not so technical (no offence), is it possible for you to put file in `google drive` or `dropbpx` and share it so that I can guide you on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi

I have shared the 2 basic example workbooks with you to give you an idea of what I meant. If I could learn the principle then I would use the same method for some other data sets on other workbooks too.

I really appreciate your time.

Kind regards

Steve

Comment: Where have you shared this. Link?